# Android: ICS Webview turns white after dialog closed

Tags: android, android-webview

On ICS (only as far as I can tell), when I open a radio element or another dialog element in a webview, once that element is closed, I get a white screen, except for the radio box. Elements can still be clicked on in the webview, and once clicked, they are redrawn and visible.

I've found that `webview.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_NONE, null)` fixes this issue, but I don't understand why. I have hardware acceleration on.

What's going on here? Is setting the layer type to none ok? Is there another approach that would work?

Answer (score 6):

Try disabling HW-acceleration on your Activity (with `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"`) that contains the WebView. You can also try disabling HW-acc. only on your WebView - which is exactly what you did with `LAYER_TYPE_NONE` ;).

- `LAYER_TYPE_NONE`: the View is rendered normally, and is not backed by an off-screen buffer.
- `LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE`: the View is rendered in hardware into a hardware texture if the application is hardware accelerated. If the application is not hardware accelerated, this layer type behaves the same as `LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE`.
- `LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE`: the View is rendered in software into a bitmap